# Casting generic type list to specific type list

Tags: c#, list, generics, casting

I have a generic method 'GetSomeData' that returns a list. I can be a list of int, double, uint...

```
public void GenericMethod<T>()
{
   List<T> genericList = GetSomeData<T>();
   List<double> castedList1 = (List<double>) genericList;
   List<double> castedList2 = genericList.Cast<double>();  //Not working
   List<double> castedList3 = genericList.Select(f => (double)f).ToList(); //not working
}
```

T can be int, uint, double...

Is there a way to cast this list?

Comment: If I called GenericMethod<Tuple<string, string>>(), I'd end up with a List<Tuple<string,string>>. How would you expect that to be cast to a List<double>?

Comment: How you can ensure that `T` is `int`, `uint` or `double`?

Comment: OK. I understand. But, then, what would be your workaround? I have a a List<T>, and must convert to List<double> :(

Comment: Try to use `Convert.ToDouble` as shown in the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine, but may have runtime exceptions if `T` can't be casted to `double`

```
public void GenericMethod<T>() where T : struct
{
   List<T> genericList = GetSomeData<T>();

   IList<double> doubleList = genericList.Select(val => Convert.ToDouble(val))
                                         .ToList();
}
```

Comment: What is the meaning of this type of approach? Why we can't use just `List<double> genericList = GetSomeData<double>();`?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan this is a question to the OP. I'm not aware of the `GetSomeData<T>` implementation, nor do I know the meaning of `T` type parameter. OP wanted to cast `List<T>` with open type to `List<double>` and I gave him an example of doing so.

Comment: @Hamlet, GetSomeData<T> is a method that fills a list with the data in a DataTable, wich can be int, uint, byte, decimal... All numeric types. I didn't want to enter deep in my code, to focus in my problem. In fact, this is the last step in a BIG trouble with types defined in runtime using GetType(). To avoid conditionals and 'switch', I use 'MethodInfo.Invoke' to pass it to  GenericMethod<T>.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
List<double> castedList3 = genericList.OfType<double>().ToList();
```

Comment: That isn't casting the list, though - it is making a new separate list of the elements of a given type

Comment: @MarcGravell ignoring all items in the original, which can't be casted.